# 1D wave equation: Numerical approximation of GreenFunction (MethodOfLines)

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Trying to find a numerical approximation "GreenFunction of the waveequation"  ('GreenFunction` doesn't evaluate) Mathematica "MethodOfLines" won't evaluate:

With

```
\[CurlyEpsilon] = .01;
dirac = 1/Sqrt[2 Pi \[CurlyEpsilon]] Exp[-(#^2/(2 \[CurlyEpsilon]))] &
```

I try to solve the pde `Derivative[2, 0][u][t, x] - Derivative[ 0, 2][u][t, x] ==  dirac[t - \[Tau]] dirac[x - \[Xi]]` using `MethodOfLines`

```
U = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][u][t, x] -Derivative[ 0, 2][u][t, x] == 
dirac[t - \[Tau]] dirac[x - \[Xi]]
, u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0,u[0, x] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 1}  , {\[Tau], \[Xi]}   , 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> { "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}} ,MaxStepSize -> .01 ]
```

If I try to plot the solution

```
Plot3D[ U[1/2, 1/2][t, x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2} ]
```

Mathematica doesn't plot and gives error message `ParametricNDSolveValue::tvic: t$17452 cannot be used as the temporal independent variable because the conditions {u[0,x$17453]==0} for that dimension do not constitute sufficient initial conditions given at only one value of t$17452.` which I don't understand.

What could be the reason for this error and how could I avoid?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to specify a derivative of the initial condition.

Comment: Also see the ref page of the message: ref/message/NDSolve/tvic

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work!